# Display First 2 records of File in android

Tags: android

In android to display file contains i wrote following code

```
BufferedReader myReader = null;
                try 
                {
                    fIn = openFileInput("lost_test.txt");           
                    myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String aDataRow = "";
                String aBuffer = "";
                try 
                {
                    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),aBuffer+"\n",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
```

Here i displayed the whole file contains but i want to display only First 2 records means Toast them individually in android how can i do this

Comment: First 2 recoreds means First two lines from the file . am i correct?

Comment: yes exact that i want to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),aDataRow,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                  aDataRow="";
                                                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

i want you to have bit modification please place your text file in res/raw folder, create raw folder under res,
then to read the file you can use directly `R.raw.lost_test`
code below,

```
 int id=R.raw. int id=R.raw.lost_test;
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(id);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        String readLine;
        int count=0;
        while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null && count < 2) {   
            count++;

             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),readLine,
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: dude i want to get items without creating raw folder

Comment: use your code along with `int count=0;` and `while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null && count <2 ) { count++;  aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),aBuffer+"\n",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: AFAIK it should come out of while loop after count =2